# Unable to get image in Canvas element to appear as DIV background image (HTML/Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas

I have a web page that displays an image in a **CANVAS** element that is a child to a DIV element.  I want to be able to grab the image from a **CANVAS** element and put it into a DIV that I will move around the screen.  I am using the code below to try and do this.  The Javascript code assigns the value of the **canvas.toDataURL()** method, wrapped in a "url()" method call, to the **background image** of the **DIV** using the JQuery CSS() method.  I checked in the Chrome debugger console and the **backround-image** property of the DIV *is* set to the value returned by the **canvas.toDataURL()** method.  I can see it in the **backgroundImage** field that is listed as a child of the DIV's **Style** property.  However if I set a Watch expression to **$("#easter-egg-cat-1").css("backround-image")** it returns "none" as the value.

In any case I don't see the background image in the DIV.  Why is this and how can I fix it?

```
<!-- THESE ARE THE WEB PAGE ELEMENTS INVOLVED -->
<div id="viewer-container">
    <!-- This DIV is where any warning messages will be displayed if a cat's face can not be 
          detected properly in the uploaded photo.  -->
    <div class="kittydar-viewer" id="kittydar-viewer"></div>
    <div id="viewer">
        <canvas id="preview">
        </canvas>
        <canvas id="annotations">
        </canvas>
    </div>
    <!-- This is where progress messages from the KittyDar detector are displayed as it searches for a cat face in the uploaded picture. -->
    <div class="kittydar-progress" id="kittydar-progress">(none)</div>
</div>


// This is the script that grabs the image from the CANVAS element and sets the
//  the desired DIVs background-image CSS property to the URL provided by the
//  CANVAS element.
var previewCanvasAsUrl = $("#preview").get(0).toDataURL();

$("#easter-egg-cat-1").css("backround-image", "url(" + previewCanvasAsUrl + ")");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
$("#easter-egg-cat-1").css("background-image", "url(" + previewCanvasAsUrl + ")");
                                ^
```

Comment: Thanks @dmk.  I stared at that code for hours and didn't notice that.  Any idea on how the backgroundImage field in the Chrome debugger managed to show a value despite my typo?  Just curious.